# Material-UI Rating Component does not update star rating correctly

Tags: css, reactjs

I have managed to get the [Material UI Rating Component](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/) to work. However, when I click on the rating, the rating does not update.

This is what I have so far.

```
const Product = props => {
const [rating, setRating] = useState(cumRating);

const updateRating = (newRating) => {
    setRating(newRating);
    console.log(rating);
}
return (
    <Rating
        value={rating}
        precision={0.5}
        max={5}
        name="hover-feedback"
        onChange={(event, newValue) => updateRating(newValue)}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
            setHover(newHover);
        }}
    />
)
```

}

When I do console.log(rating), it prints out the right rating, but it won't update the star UI component.

Then I removed the name attribute in rating, and it worked. But I get this error. Is there some sort of workaround to hide this error?

Why is this error creeping up? 
What exactly does this name attribute do? 
I tried to set readOnly to true, but I no longer get the hover effect, which I wanted.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: The prop `name` is required (when `readOnly` is false).
Additionally, the input name should be unique within the parent form.
    in ForwardRef(Rating) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Rating)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Rating)) (at Product.js:86)
    in div (created by CardBody)
    in CardBody (at Product.js:82)
    in div (created by Card)
    in Card (at Product.js:65)
    in Product (at Products.js:104)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (at Products.js:189)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div
    in Motion
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div
    in t
    in r
    in r
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by Measure)
    in Measure
    in r (at Products.js:175)
    in div (at Products.js:174)
    in div (at Products.js:168)
    in Products (at Home/index.js:163)
    in div (at Home/index.js:160)
    in Home (at App.js:40)
    in main (at App.js:39)
    in div (at App.js:37)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.web.js:10)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at registerRootComponent.web.js:6)
    in RootComponent
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Comment: Do you have any other Rating component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify this

```
<Rating
        value={rating}
        precision={0.5}
        max={5}
        name="hover-feedback"
        onChange={(event, newValue) => updateRating(newValue)}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
            setHover(newHover);
        }}
    />
```

to this:

```
<Rating
        value={rating}
        precision={0.5}
        max={5}
        name="unique-rating"
        onChange={(event, newValue) => updateRating(newValue)}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
            setHover(newHover);
        }}
    />
```

According to docs:

> The name attribute of the radio input elements. If readOnly is false, the prop is required, this input name`should be unique within the parent form.

The issue can occur if you have multiple components with same `name` attribute.

Comment: Cool, I realized that shortly after I posted. Thank you anyways! I did have multiple components with the same name attribute.